# Embedded graphical interface for Rest API testing

Tags: javascript, html, rest

I'm developing an api in C, but I would like to embed a "postman" alongside it in a "/test" route, for example.

Where, when accessing the api url in /test , a test interface would open to test the api, being able to place values for headders and params in the specified routes

Does anyone know of a javascript lib to do this, it has to be pure js, so I can embed it statically in html.

Creating another server for this is out of the question (unnecessary complexity), I just need it to have a nice interface, and I can specify the routes and inputs for each route, with a send button, so that API users can test .

I searched about but didint found nothing